# TeX doesn't recognize built-in control sequences?

Tags: errors, tex-core, plain-tex

I'm trying to learn to build things from the ground-up with TeX (not LaTeX---I've used LaTeX before, so I know how easy a solution "`\usepackage{amsthm}`+`\begin{theorem}`" is) and I'm trying to build my own theorem environment that, among other things, indents on both the left and right. I know what `\narrower` and `\leftskip` (`\rightskip`) do. However, TeX doesn't recognize these control sequences.

```
\def\thm[#1]{\par {\leftskip 1in \rightskip 1in %
  \noindent {\bf Theorem.} {\it #1 \/} \newline \noindent}
\def\endthm{ } \par}
```

Upon compile (by the way, that's:

```
pdftex def.tex
* \input sandbox.tex
```

where `def.tex` contains this and `sandbox.tex` contains

```
\thm[Name of theorem] Blah blah \endthm
```

) I get the error saying "Undefined control sequence." So what's going on? I got the impression from my readings that these (`\leftskip`, &c.) are built into TeX, so it shouldn't be a package issue.

Also, that `\noindent` at the end of the second line doesn't work, but that's less annoying at the moment.

Comment: What makes you think that `\newline` is defined in Plain TeX?

Comment: @egreg, because the output skipped a line. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\newline` is not defined in Plain TeX. There are also other problems in your code: you set `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` but close the group before it can act.

```
\input plipsum % for mock text

\def\thm[#1]{%
  \par % get in vertical mode
  \begingroup % open a group
  \leftskip 1in \rightskip 1in % set the margins
  \noindent {\bf Theorem.} {\it #1}\par\nobreak % print the header
  \noindent\ignorespaces % print the statement
}
\def\endthm{\par\endgroup} % end the paragraph and restore the margins

\lipsum 1

\thm[Name]
\lipsum 2
\endthm

\lipsum 3

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I'll add the spacing before and after the environment (desirable) is obtained with  \hfill  before the first  \par  and an  \hfill  after the last one.

Comment: @D.Weathers This last staement is confusing. `\hfill` before the first `\par` would be horizontal space added to the previous paragraph, and would have no effect on that paragraph. Adding `\hfill` after the last `\par` would end up at the start of the following line. Surely you mean to add *vertical* space (maybe `\bigskip`) *after* both `\par`s.